# Google profiles search API

Tags: google-search-api

Does the Google search API support searches for Google profiles? I looked through the google code pages but could not find it. I only found an API for getting the profile data when you know the username and got permission, but could not find a search option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there is a search page that can be screenscaped. An API is not yet available.

http://www.google.com/profiles?q=